# Как нажать на кнопку в диалоговом окне Windows, открытым из Firefox (исключение безопасности)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, uiautomation

Пишу парсер, который после открытия адреса последовательно нажимает первую кнопку, вторую, открывает диалоговое окно (windo'вое) и в нём нужно нажать третью кнопку. Как это реализовать? Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю тут надо юзать связку autoit selenium webdriver

Comment: http://internetka.in.ua/autoit-file-upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Программно жать такие кнопки может быть необходимость только если непосредственно тестируете свою сборку Firefox под Windows.
2. Если нужно просто воспользоваться сайтом, то лучше запускать Firefox с такими ключами (`desired_capabilities` в терминах Selenium Webdriver), которые заставят его игнорировть ту проблему безопасности, о которой всплывающее окно.
3. Но скорее всего Selenium вообще не нужен, и нужно смотреть в сторону библиотек, которые умеют ходить по сайтам без браузера. Под Ruby это  Mechanize ([примеры использования](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html)). Под Java это, вероятно JSoup ([ответ на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9071568/322020)].

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать 2 вариант.